# Json out put from php is adding some extra charecters to it

Tags: php, json

i am trying to output json for my web application http://www.mohammediatechnologies.in/fbdownload/youtubedl.php?name=www.facebook.com/ladygaga/videos/vb.10376464573/10153640467779574/?type=2&theater for this url mentioned json is not properly formatted with extra strings i am using following code.

```
$urlf = json_encode(array( ''=> $result));
echo $ urlf;
```

and `$result` is properly formatted json any help will be appreciated i am stuck here

Comment: What extra strings are you seeing?

Comment: please re check once json start with {"":[" which i dont required i am doing string replace to get output but some times i miss some charecters by doing it manually. thats why i posted this question asking for why i am getting this

Comment: Provide the json response in your question and the content of your $result variable.

Comment: jsonline.com reports a problem in the `title` property: `"title": "\\"mummy don't bother me I'm with daddy\\" - Miss Asia Kinney",` The backslashes shouldn't be doubled. Please show how you're creating `$result`.

Comment: i am using  $f=$_GET["name"];
  $f = str_replace('https://','',$f);
 
      $string = 'python youtube-dl  --print-json -s '.$f;
 ]
 //echo $string;
   
    exec($string, $result, $status);  i am using youtube-dl

Comment: jsonline.com is this site you meant could you give me full url where i can check please re check the json string again

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include additional information, rather than add it in comments.